# Mostrar Confirm de JS diferentes segun el boton presionado para confirmar enviar o no formulario

Tags: javascript, html

intento mostrar Mensajes "confirm" JS diferentes segun el boton que se presione, muestra el "confirm" pero aunque cancele igual ejecuta el submit. de antemano muchas gracias.

Archivo JS:

```
function confirmar_addPlanilla() {
    if (confirm("¿Seguro que desea Agregar la Planilla?")) {
        return true;
        } else {
        return false; }
    }
function confirmar_delPlanilla() {
    if (confirm("¿Seguro que desea eliminar la Planilla? Cuidado, Esto no podra deshacerse")){
        return true;
        } else {
        return false; }
}
```

HTML:

```
    <form method='POST' action='file.html'>
<button type='submit' onclick='confirmar_delPlanilla()' value='' name='eliminar'>Eliminar</button>

<button type='submit' onclick='confirmar_addPlanilla()' value='' name='aprobar'>Aprobar</button></form>
```

Comment: Eso te ocurre porque en ningún momento estas vigilando el evento `submit` del botón. Tan solo lanzas un `confirm` pero igualmente lo ejecuta porque no lo paras con `preventDefault()` en las funciones. Tampoco tiene mucho sentido que ambos botones acaben ejecutando lo mismo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero sigo sin poder solucionar el problema. no se como implemento el preventDefault(). intente algunas cosas y no pude.

Comment: Mirate mi respuesta que acabo de agregar, aunque la sigo documentando, pero ya funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mírate mi solución a tu pregunta:

```js
document.getElementsByName("aprobar")[0].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (!confirm("¿Seguro que desea Agregar la Planilla?")) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
})
document.getElementsByName("eliminar")[0].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (!confirm("¿Seguro que desea eliminar la Planilla? Cuidado, Esto no podra deshacerse")) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<form method='POST' action='file.html'>
  <button type='submit' value='' name='eliminar'>Eliminar</button>
  <button type='submit' value='' name='aprobar'>Aprobar</button>
</form>
```

Tal como te decia antes, no tenias controlado el evento `submit` mediante la función `preventDefault`.

**Explicación de los cambios:**

En lugar de ejecutar las acciones mediante `onclick` ahora son vigiladas con `addEventListener` sobre los elementos con el `name` correspondiente seleccionado mediante `getElementsByName` donde escogemos su número de indice 0 (el primero) porque no hay más que uno.

1. Por lo tanto el primer cambio ha sido eliminar los eventos `onclick` en los botones.
2. Al no usar las funciones por nombre, sino controlarlos por el evento `click` y el `name` del elemento, el formato de cada intercepción es:

   ```
   document.getElementsByName("xxxx")[0].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
   ```

   donde **xxxx** representa el atributo `name` del elemento a vigilar.
3. El condicional if lo he modificado por lo siguiente:

   ```
   if (!confirm("¿Seguro que desea Agregar la Planilla?")) {
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
   }
   ```

   donde he aplicado un operador de negación `!` sobre el `confirm`
   para que actue cuando el usuario **no acepta** la pregunta.

   Y en caso de no aceptarla se paraliza el evento del elemento que ha recibido el click mediante event.preventDefault.

   En caso de aceptarla no hacemos nada y por lo tanto el submit es ejecutado tal cual sin ningun bloqueo.

Comment: Funciona Perfecto. muy agradecido. no sabes cuanto habia buscado la solucion.